# add data into combobox using extjs

Tags: rest, extjs

Hi I have a combo box which have a store that is based on rest call and populate data from data base, its working fine but i need a value 'All' with all the values coming from data base so how can i do this please suggest

```
var wardName =  Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
                id : 'visittype',

                fields : [
                        {
                            name : 'id',
                            type : 'integer',
                        },
                        {
                            name : 'wardName',

                        }
                        ],

                remoteGroup : true,
                remoteSort : true,
                proxy : {
                    type : 'rest',
                    url : 'pmsRest/wards',


                    reader : {

                        root : "wardMaster",
                        idProperty : 'id'
                    }

                },
                    autoLoad : true,

            });


{
                                                xtype : 'combo',
                                                name : 'wardName',
                                                labelStyle : 'color:black;font-weight:bold;width:250px;padding:10;',
                                                labelSeparator : "",

                                                id : 'wardName',
                                                width:'33%',
                                                fieldLabel : 'Ward',
                                                triggerAction : 'all',
                                                store : wardName,
                                                displayField : 'wardName',
                                                valueField : 'id',
                                                multiSelect : false,
                                                typeAhead : true,
                                                //disabled: true,
                                                listeners : {
                                                    change : function(combo) {
                                                     Ext.getCmp('bedName').bindStore(loadBedName());
                                                    }

                                                },
                                                allowBlank : false,
                                                //enableKeyEvents : true,

                                        },
```

Comment: please suggest any solution how can i add one more value static value"All"

Comment: do you need the store in another component? if not, you could hook into the load event of the store and add your `All` value

Comment: how to do this can you give me syntex for this

Answer (score 0):

Once the data from the proxy is loaded successfully you can use the insert method of store to add the static data in store.

insert method inserts Model instances into the Store at the given index.

The syntax is store.insert( index, records ) where index is the position at which you want to insert the instance, in this case it would be 0.

hope it helps you. :-)

Comment: sorry i am new at extjs so please can u give me more explanation how can i use insert in this code or where

Answer (score 0):

Add a listener to the store and a load event. In that event you can add a new item to the store when the store is loaded.

```
listeners: {
    load: function(){
        this.add({
            id: 0,
            name: 'All'
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the error message? do you already have a record in your store with `id: 0`?